# Run a project without source .java files in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a java project in Eclipse that I am trying to run/debug.
When I run the project Eclipse goes into Debug mode and then throws a ClassNotFound Exception.
I have a class folder in the default package in my project that contains all the necessary class files. Any help regarding this would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: This is a Java project and I have the correct class paths and directories set properly. The project runs alright if I also include the source folder in the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The classes folder needs to be added to the project's classpath. Putting classes into the source directory isn't going to work. Go to project properties -> Java Build Path to configure this.

Comment: Yes I already did that. The thing is, the project works fine if I also add a source folder to the project. But if I "run" without the source folder thats when it throws the exception

Comment: I am not following. Could you post the contents if your project's .classpath file?

Comment: So, I have a java project, In there I have a class folder(inside the deafault package) which has all my application classes(including a main) that I want to run. Also I have my classpath set so that all the necessary library class files(such as JRE, soot etc )are available to the project. I tried to debug this thing but when I try to insert a breakpoint Eclipse gives me an error that "line number info is missing", although the classes do have the linenumbertable(i checked by doing a javap).

Comment: That's not enough info to help you. Look at your project root directory. There is going to be a file called .classpath. Please post the contents of that file along with a description of where exactly you've placed your class file. Give a path to the class file that is not being found.

Comment: Well it suddenly works now :-s I am not sure how though...I just terminated everything in the debug mode, did a refresh on the project and did "run" and it works now. But since you mentioned it, I dont see any .classpath file in my project root directory. I just have my class folder, output folder and source folder which is empty.

Comment: The Project Explorer or Package Explorer view will filter out all files that start with a dot. Take a look at your project directory using your operating system's facilities. If you are not on Windows, your OS may also be filtering out these files. Disable the filtering to see them.

Comment: yeah I am working on Linux.I can see the .classpath file now :) Thanks for your help. :)